# papyrus installation error

Tags: eclipse, eclipse-plugin, installation, uml, papyrus

While installing **Papyrus via Eclipse Juno Help** - Install New Software, I have this error ;

```
Cannot complete the install because one or more required items could not be found.
  Software being installed: Papyrus customization (Incubation) 0.9.1.v201209190809 (org.eclipse.papyrus.customization.feature.feature.group 0.9.1.v201209190809)
  Missing requirement: Papyrus properties generation (Incubation) 0.9.1.v201209190809 (org.eclipse.papyrus.customization.properties.generation 0.9.1.v201209190809) requires 'bundle org.eclipse.m2m.qvt.oml.project 3.1.0' but it could not be found
  Cannot satisfy dependency:
    From: Papyrus customization (Incubation) 0.9.1.v201209190809 (org.eclipse.papyrus.customization.feature.feature.group 0.9.1.v201209190809)
    To: org.eclipse.papyrus.customization.properties.generation [0.9.1.v201209190809]
```

What should I do to resolve this problem ?

Answer (score 1):

I would suggest you to follow Kepler's version of Papyrus

Please follow the following ticket

[Intsalling Papyrus on Kepler](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14967430/how-to-install-papyrus-kepler-fo-eclipse-4-2-1/17418227#17418227)