# How to install Papyrus for Eclipse - Kepler?

Tags: eclipse-plugin, papyrus

I want to install papyrus kepler version 0.10.x for eclipse 4.2.1, but I have always 
the same error message below:

Cannot complete the install because one or more required items could not be found.
  Software being installed: Papyrus UML (Incubation) 0.10.0.v201302191641 (org.eclipse.papyrus.sdk.feature.feature.group 0.10.0.v2013021916

I need to install this version of papyrus but i didn't found a solution so can you help me please.

Thanks in advance :)

Comment: Why do you need to install a Kepler (4.3) version of the plugin for Juno (4.2).  The previous version is likely meant for Kepler.  Also, Kepler was just released this week so you might have been working with something in flight.

Answer (score 13):

I have tried the following steps to install Papyrus on Kepler
After installaing eclipse-standard-kepler-R-win32 from Eclipse.org

1. Click on Help->Install new software and select  update site Kepler -
   http://download.eclipse.org/releases/kepler
2. Select Modelling and click next. Install it first.
3. Once you restart Eclipse after installing Modelling, you can see
   that there will be one menu item in the help menu with text
   "Install Modelling components" select it
4. You can see that Papyrus will be shown in the next dialog. Select
   and install it.

Comment: It would be nice to know the SPECIFIC package to get the 'install modeling components' option.  Installing ALL modelling packages seems like overkill.